# Xcode - Copy Resource through Finder

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I copy resources to a Xcode project bundle by using Finder or the command line? I have tried to copy the directories the project root and added the following to the **project.pbxproj**:

```
801C4BD81F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPRequestOperation.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BB11F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPRequestOperation.m */; };
801C4BD91F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BB31F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m */; };
801C4BDA1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPSessionManager.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BB51F2A804F007764A7 /* AFHTTPSessionManager.m */; };
801C4BDB1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BB81F2A804F007764A7 /* AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m */; };
801C4BDC1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFSecurityPolicy.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BBA1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFSecurityPolicy.m */; };
801C4BDD1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLConnectionOperation.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BBC1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLConnectionOperation.m */; };
801C4BDE1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLRequestSerialization.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BBE1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLRequestSerialization.m */; };
801C4BDF1F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLResponseSerialization.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BC01F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLResponseSerialization.m */; };
801C4BE01F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLSessionManager.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BC21F2A804F007764A7 /* AFURLSessionManager.m */; };
801C4BE11F2A804F007764A7 /* AFAutoPurgingImageCache.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BC51F2A804F007764A7 /* AFAutoPurgingImageCache.m */; };
801C4BE21F2A804F007764A7 /* AFImageDownloader.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BC71F2A804F007764A7 /* AFImageDownloader.m */; };
801C4BE31F2A804F007764A7 /* AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BC91F2A804F007764A7 /* AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.m */; };
801C4BE41F2A804F007764A7 /* UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BCB1F2A804F007764A7 /* UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.m */; };
801C4BE51F2A804F007764A7 /* UIButton+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BCD1F2A804F007764A7 /* UIButton+AFNetworking.m */; };
801C4BE61F2A804F007764A7 /* UIImageView+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BD01F2A804F007764A7 /* UIImageView+AFNetworking.m */; };
801C4BE71F2A804F007764A7 /* UIProgressView+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BD31F2A804F007764A7 /* UIProgressView+AFNetworking.m */; };
801C4BE81F2A804F007764A7 /* UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BD51F2A804F007764A7 /* UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.m */; };
801C4BE91F2A804F007764A7 /* UIWebView+AFNetworking.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 801C4BD71F2A804F007764A7 /* UIWebView+AFNetworking.m */; };
```

This results in a linker error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I add resources to the bundle without having to use the Xcode application? I am looking to do this outside the Xcode application.